# Trying to find highest palindromic product of 2 3 digit numbers

Tags: java, palindrome

```
public class Script_4
{
/*
A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
*/
public static void main (String [] Args)
{
    int highest_palindrome = 0;
    int product;
    int length;
    String product_string;
    for (int num = 100; num < 1000; num ++)
    {
        for ( int inside_num = 100; inside_num < 1000; inside_num ++) {
            product = num * inside_num;
            product_string = Integer.toString(product);
            length = product_string.length();
            if (length == 5) {
                int[] numbers_array = new int[5];
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    numbers_array[i] = Integer.parseInt(product_string.substring(i, i + 1));
                }
                if (numbers_array[0] == numbers_array[4]) {
                    if (numbers_array[1] == numbers_array[3]) {
                        highest_palindrome = product;
                    }
                }

            } else if (length == 6) {
                int[] numbers_array = new int[6];
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    numbers_array[i] = Integer.parseInt((product_string.substring(i, i + 1)));
                }
                if (numbers_array[0] == numbers_array[5]) {
                    if (numbers_array[1] == numbers_array[4]) {
                        if (numbers_array[2] == numbers_array[3]) {
                            highest_palindrome = product;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    System.out.println(highest_palindrome);
}
}
```

My program is expected to output the highest palindromic product of two three digit numbers. When I run this program, my output is "99299", whereas it should be far higher. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks so much for any help, any is appreciated. I just started learning Java last week and so this is my way of implementing that knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but I thought that the product could also be six digits wrong, in which case I would be dealing with different index vaues. I don't really see how there is an issue in this. Thanks!

Comment: `if (length == 6)` but `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. Don't you mean `i < 6`?

Comment: Calling `substring` and `parse` to extract and convert a digit character to a number is very slow. `Integer.parseInt(product_string.substring(i, i + 1))` is better written as `product_string.charAt(i) - '0'`, or perhaps `Character.digit(product_string.charAt(i), 10)`

Comment: That does change the value to "580085", but this is still wrong. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? What is the right answer?

Comment: The correct answer is supposed to be 906609.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that you think any palindrome you find is the highest. Perhaps you need an `if` statement, e.g. `if (product > highest_palindrome) { highest_palindrome = product; }`

Comment: Perfect! That fixed it! For some reason some part of me assumed the numbers would gradually ascend (for getting about the fact that the outer loop loops back to 100 each iteration). Thank you so much kind stranger!

Comment: Part of reason is because you're doubling the work to be done. Remember, `123 * 456` is the same as `456 * 123`, so there is no need to check both. To eliminate double checking, only check products of numbers where second number is greater than or equal to first number.